# Como inserir um gráfico como subrelatório em WPF Report Viewer

Tags: c#, wpf, relatório, reportviewer

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em WPF e preciso inserir alguns gráficos em um relatório. Criei dois arquivos .RDLC um chamado de InfoGrafico e outro de SubInfoGrafico. Em meu subrelatório gostaria de adicionar um gráfico contendo algumas informações do banco que são obtidas através de um DataSet.

```
private void ImpRelatorio(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            RVInfoGrafico.Reset();
            RVInfoGrafico.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            RVInfoGrafico.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(MSubreportProcessingEventHandler);

            DataTable dt = GetData2();
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
            RVInfoGrafico.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            RVInfoGrafico.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Projeto.InfoGrafico.rdlc";

            RVInfoGrafico.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            RVInfoGrafico.RefreshReport();

        }
        void MSubreportProcessingEventHandler(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt9 = GetData4();
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1",dt9));
        }
```

Bom acontece que quando eu insiro um gráfico sempre dá um erro `O Sub-relatório 'Subreport1' não pôde ser encontrado no local especificado Projeto.SubInfoGrafico.rdlc. Verifique se o sub-relatório foi publicado e se o nome está correto.` Quando eu insiro uma tabela ou qualquer outro tool funciona perfeitamente com os datasets e tal... Somente estou tendo problemas com Gráfico.

Comment: o valor do source não está correto, certo, você já tentou colocar @"nome-do-componente" ou @"../diretoriodocompoente/nomedocomponente ?

Comment: @JcSaint Não é isso. Mas já consegui resolver o problema é que no meu gráfico não tinha configurado um `group value`.